# Trying to implement a body tag color change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I'm learning Javascript/JQuery.

I'm writing a guess-a-number game and I'm trying to `.animate()` a `backgroundColor` change on an `id` if the user guesses incorrectly. I have seen a few examples of this and found one in particular at the JQuery site which I'm trying to use.

You can see the code here: https://github.com/thecompu/hc

Otherwise, it's below.

Note: If you run the `index.html` in your browser, the randomized number is logged to the console, but if you don't have the console open, you won't see it. The number selection is only between 1 and 10, though.

What happens now is if you guess the wrong number, you're prompted again, as I want. But I also want the body background to change color to red. Instead, the background color is changed after the user gives the correct answer and is NOT animated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    console.log(answer);

    function game() {
        var guess = prompt("Choose a number!");
        guess = Number(guess);
        if (guess !== answer) {
            $("#bg").animate({
                backgroundColor: "#F00",
                color: "#000",
            }, 1000);
            console.log("Nope!");
            game();
        } else {
            console.log("Yay!");
        }
    }
    game();
});
```

Comment: I believe you need `jquery.color` to animate color: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Comment: I'm positively sure @DanielGimenez is correct, a color plugin or jQuery UI is needed to animate colors.

Comment: Use CSS and apply a class with transitions if they guess incorrectly.

Comment: I forked your project with my answer.  https://github.com/DDtMM/hc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot animate background color using jQuery natively. However, you CAN use CSS transitions to do the same, using only body classes.

**CSS**

```
body
{
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
}

body.blue
{
    background: blue;
}

body.red
{
    background: red;
}
```

Then simply add a class to the body using javascript, like in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/bUNkJ/

Answer (score 1):

Even with jquery color included in the project the problem still persists.  The source of the problem is the use of `prompt`.  It prevents browser execution from occurring, and since you keep re-calling it, you never give the animation a chance to occur.

Here is an event driven approach using jquery-ui (it was part of your project) as well as jquery.color.  It is far from perfect, but you get the idea:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#guessPrompt').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {}
    });

    $('#guessInput').keypress(function () {
        if ($('#guessInput').val() != answer) {
            $('#guessInput').val('');
            $('#guessPrompt').dialog('close');
            $("#bg").animate({
                backgroundColor: "#F00",
                color: "#000"
            }, {
                duration: 1000,
                always: function () {
                    console.log('hi');
                    $('#guessPrompt').dialog('open');
                    $('#bg').css('backgroundColor', '#888');
                }
            });
            console.log('Nope');
        } else {
            console.log('yay');
        }
    });
    var answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) +1;
    $('#guessPrompt').dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: Wow. Definitely a bit more for me to chew on! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Prompt was the source of the problem, find another way to get the input and you should be good to go, or wait to prompt after the animation is complete.

Comment: The end-goal of the project will be using a form on a webpage, not the prompt. So, in the end the prompt won't be a factor.